# Cakephp3 multiple join table by Model

Tags: mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I have problem with my code. At this moment I have code view like this:

```
...Table.php

    public function containBasic(){
        return [
         //Keywords
         'CandidatesKeywords',
         'CandidatesKeywords.Keywords',

         //User
         'CandidatesUser',
         'CandidatesUser.User',
        ];
    }

...Controller.php

$this->loadModel('Candidates');
$candidates = $this->Candidates->find()
    ->contain($this->Candidates->containBasic())
    ->where([
        'CandidatesKeywords.Keywords.id'=>5
        ])
    ->all();
```

I include all other Models via contain. This method its works but when I try to search data in this code I have error like:

> Unknown column 'CandidatesKeyword.id' in 'where clause

I don't know, how I can get column CandidatesKeywords -> Keywords -> Id from database :/

When I get (debug) all rows without where condition I get data like this:

```
'items' => [
        (int) 0 => object(Cake\ORM\Entity) {

            'id' => (int) 4,
            .........
            ,
            'candidates_user' => null,
            'candidates_keyword' => object(App\Model\Entity\CandidatesKeyword) {

                'id' => (int) 1,
                ..................
                'keyword' => object(App\Model\Entity\Keyword) {

                    'id' => (int) 5,
                    .............
```

And I need to get rows with only keyword.id = 5.

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong but I think you need to use [matching](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#filtering-by-associated-data-via-matching-and-joins)

Comment: Thanks for reply, I try this tomorrow because today I'm use contain without functions ;)

Comment: You are containing CandidatesKeywords, plural, but your where clause appears to have CandidatesKeyword, singular, in it somehow. It's not that way in any of the code you've shown, so anyone's guess at this point where it's coming from.